# Embed flash content for Windows Store App

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, windows-store-apps

I need to embed a .swf (flash) file in my web page. The web page and its assets are located on local hard drive. I used to embed it for IE like this:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
```

But it does not work for metro IE 10 on windows 8. IE 10 in metro mode can not open this. How can I fix this for IE in metro mode?

Comment: This will not helping your situation, I'm sure... but anyway I want to say it; you can think to use silverlight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is only allowed on sites which make it on to a pre-approved list: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-8/97346-submit-sites-flash-enabled-metro-ie10.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, there's no way to display flash in IE10 Metro.